# PDF document conversion

Tags: pdf, document

Does anyone know of an existing automated PDF conversion solution for sharepoint that works across multiple document versions?

The solutions I found so far only work based on a source/destination-list approach. Meaning you get an additional physical file after the conversion. However I look for a solution that allows me to download a PDF from any version of a document on the fly (some caching of course).

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

Call me biased, but the company I work for has a very flexible SharePoint PDF Conversion solution that you can probably use to achieve what you are after.

I'll keep the marketing babble to a minimum, just [visit this page](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-for-SharePoint/summary.aspx) for more information

Your requirement is very specific and it is unlikely that anyone will support that functionality in a generic version of a product. Having said that, you can invoke our PDF Converter via your own .net based SharePoint code, a Web Service or via a workflow. I have included examples articles below:

- [Use from your own .net code](http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2009/10/using-pdf-converter-for-sharepoint-from.html).
- [Use from a web service](http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2009/12/converting-office-files-to-pdf-format.html).
- [Use from a workflow](http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2010/01/configure-pdf-security-from-sharepoint.html).

If you have any specific questions or need for assistance then I am happy to help you on this thread. Alternatively you can [contact us directly](http://www.muhimbi.com/contact.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll have a look.
About our "special" requirement, do you mean the on-the-fly approach or the across-versions approach? I think it makes sense to let users focus on the source document only, without having to deal with the generated copies of it and where they are stored, etc.

Comment: On the fly should not be a problem, depending on your definition of 'on the fly'. The problem is to convert any historical version to PDF. This is not necessarily programmatically difficult, it is just how you let users access this functionality. The way I see it work is to let the user select a PDF Conversion option from the context menu and then show a page that allows them to choose a particular version.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any development skills you could take a look at oracle OIT PDF Export (http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/content-management/oit/oit_dl_otn.html). This provides a SOAP web service to convert a huge range of documents. I've used it in my environment to create PDF versions of important documents for extranet deployment. It would not be a huge stretch to modify this to work in a real time environment as you required.

Took me about 2 days of dev time to get running and it is extremely flexible.

Best thing is the API is free.

Answer (score 0):

Check out their competitor [Aspose.Words for SharePoint](http://www.aspose.com/categories/sharepoint-components/aspose.words-for-sharepoint/default.aspx), which is cheaper and does not requires MS Word automation on the server.