# Does Anyone Any freeware/open source PDF converter we can use with sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007, development, pdf, third-party-software

We currently using  Active PDF software in our farm, which converts documents into pdf and merge them using our K2 back end coding,

however I am looking for something easier, well doesn't matter even if its easy to implement or not but should be free and able to convert any MS Office document (word, excel, powerpoint) into pdf format.

e.g. [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/), but its not free for commercial environment

I might even consider Developing something in C# if its possible.

Cheers

Comment: Near duplicate of http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1480/pdf-document-conversion

Comment: dont think so..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's by Oracle. Remember, it's free (you will have to confirm it with sales team) and does not give you any support.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/webcenter/content/pdfexport-101991.html

Comment: Here is article on how to use "Oracle's Outside in PDF" http://www.lifeonplanetgroove.com/2009/03/19/sharepoint-document-converter-to-pdf-using-oracle-outside-in-how-to

Comment: cheers, I will try that later on :)