# Export SharePoint site content to PPT/PDF

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a sharepoint site content that I would like to export to a PPT or PDF file, I couldn't manage to find any tool to do it, in your opinion, what is the most convenient way to perform this kind of operation .

Comment: What do you mean by "content"? You mean like a screen grab of each page?

Comment: no, I mean arranging content (text, images), from different lists and arrange them into a nicely designed PPT/PDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting HTML to PPT will be challenging at best, but tools are available for output as PDF, including SharePoint UIs and Workflow Activities.

For details see:

- [Convert HTML pages to PDF format using the SharePoint User Interface](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/09/convert-html-pages-to-pdf-format-using.html)
- [Converting SharePoint Lists to PDF format using a SharePoint Designer Workflow](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/08/converting-sharepoint-lists-to-pdf.html)
- [Convert HTML to PDF using Nintex Workflow and the PDF Converter for SharePoint](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2011/08/convert-html-to-pdf-using-nintex.html)
- [Programmatically Converting Web / HTML pages to PDF format](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/08/convert-sharepoint-html-pages-to-pdf.html)

Not free, but comes with great support.

Please note that I worked on this product so the usual disclaimers apply.

Answer (score 1):

This actually might not be that difficult, depending on exactly what you are trying to do (your question is vague). This solution requires SharePoint 2010 Enterprise and Office 2010.

1. Create a document library with columns of data that you would like to import into the document.  For example, if you would like to pull an address into the document, create an "Address" column and enter the data.
2. Create a word document by navigating to the library and choosing New -> Word document.
3. Save the word document to the SharePoint library.
4. In word, place your cursor where you would like to insert the column data. Go to Insert -> Document Properties. All of the columns contained in the SharePoint library will be listed as properties. Your "address" column will be there, for example.
5. Have a workflow on the library that converts the word document to PDF using Word Automation Services. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff181518.aspx

This will not work in PowerPoint.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is even possible, at least not without a great deal of work.
If you would like to chase the idea yourself, here is a rundown on what I *think* you may need in order to get it done:

1 - Pull all lists within the site.

2 - While accessing each list, use http://www.developerfusion.com/code/5682/create-pdf-files-on-fly-in-c/.

3 - Repeatedly call function to write PDF text for each new list.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a software to do that,

you can try a paid one I am using atm

[PDF convertor Software](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CE8QFjAA&url=http://www.activepdf.com/&ei=E_j6T6rxHIrB0QXa5fCNBw&usg=AFQjCNFtfzFbI8A-6kHlSifF-Q4SNCoQmg&sig2=aICfdiR9prmCWVJpWHcGhA)

or a free by oracle,

[Similiar question i asked few day back](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39847/does-anyone-any-freeware-open-source-pdf-converter-we-can-use-with-sharepoint-20)

Or If you meant by exporting SharePoint List Data then you can simply export it to Excel or you can export it to Access if you want attachments with it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you get what you want:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/thomsven/export-sharepoint-wiki-to-wordpdf-without-3rd-party-tools

Comment: Please add more details to your summary. Link only answers are not useful forever as links tend to break over time. Add a brief summary of the solution and use the link as a reference to your answer instead.